# How can I upload files through aiohttp using response from get request?

Tags: python, wordpress, aiohttp, python-aiofiles

To start off, I am writing an async wrapper for the WordPress REST API. I have a Wordpress site hosted on Bluehost. I am working with the endpoint for media (image) uploads. I have successfully managed to upload an image but there are 2 changes I would like to make. The second change is what I really want, but out of curiosity, I would like to know how to implement change 1 too. I'll provide the code first and then some details.

**Working code**

```
async def upload_local_pic2(self, local_url, date, title):
    url = f'{self.base_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    with aiohttp.MultipartWriter() as mpwriter:
      json = {'title': title, 'status':'publish'}
      mpwriter.append_json(json)
      with open(local_url, 'rb') as f:
        print(f)
        payload = mpwriter.append(f)
        async with self.session.post(url, data=payload) as response:
          x = await response.read()
          print(x)
```

**Change 1**

The first change is uploading using aiofiles.open() instead of just using open() as I expect to be processing lots of files. The following code does not work.

```
async def upload_local_pic(self, local_url, date, title):
    url = f'{self.base_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    with aiohttp.MultipartWriter() as mpwriter:
      json = {'title': title, 'status':'publish'}
      mpwriter.append_json(json)
      async with aiofiles.open(local_url, 'rb') as f:
        print(f)
        payload = mpwriter.append(f)
        async with self.session.post(url, data=payload) as response:
          x = await response.read()
          print(x)
```

**Change 2**

My other change is that I would like to have another function that can upload the files directly to the WordPress server without downloading them locally. So instead of getting a local picture, I want to pass in the url of an image online. The following code also does not work.

```
async def upload_pic(self, image_url, date, title):
    url = f'{self.base_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    with aiohttp.MultipartWriter() as mpwriter:
      json = {'title':title, 'status':'publish'}
      mpwriter.append_json(json)
      async with self.session.get(image_url) as image_response:
        image_content = image_response.content
        print(image_content)
        payload = mpwriter.append(image_content)
        async with self.session.post(url, data = payload) as response:
          x = await response.read()
          print(x)
```

**Details/Debugging**

I'm trying to figure out why each one won't work. I think the key is the calls to `print(image_content)`
and `print(f)` that show what exactly I am inputting to `mpwriter.append`

In the example that works where I just use the standard Python `open()` function, I am apparently passing in `<_io.BufferedReader name='/redactedfilepath/index.jpeg'>`

In the change 1 example with aiofile, I am passing in `<aiofiles.threadpool.binary.AsyncBufferedReader object at 0x7fb803122250>`
Wordpress will return this html:

`b'<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>'`

And finally, in change 2 where I try to pass in what the get request to the url gives me I get
`<StreamReader 292 bytes>`. The response returned by WordPress is the same as above with Mod Security.

Any idea how I can make these examples work? It seems like they are all some type of io reader but I guess the underlying aiohttp code treats them differently.

Also this shouldn't really matter, but [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg) is the url I am passing into the change 2 example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out both changes.

For the first change when trying to read a file with `aiofiles`, I need to just read the whole file instead of passing in the file handler. Also, I need to set the content disposition manually.

```
async def upload_local_pic(self, local_url, date, title):
    url = f'{self.base_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    with aiohttp.MultipartWriter() as mpwriter:
      json = {'status':'publish'}
      mpwriter.append_json(json)
      async with aiofiles.open(local_url, mode='rb') as f:
        contents = await f.read()
        payload = mpwriter.append(contents)
        payload.set_content_disposition('attachment', filename= title+'.jpg')
        async with self.session.post(url, data=payload) as response:
          x = await response.read()
          print(x)
```

For the second change, it's a similar concept with just uploading a file directly from the URL. Instead of passing in the handler that will read the content, I need to read the entire content first. I also need to set the content-disposition manually.

```
async def upload_pic(self, image_url, date, title):
    url = f'{self.base_url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media'
    with aiohttp.MultipartWriter() as mpwriter:
      json = {'status':'publish'}
      mpwriter.append_json(json)
      async with self.session.get(image_url) as image_response:
        image_content = await image_response.read()
        payload = mpwriter.append(image_content)
        payload.set_content_disposition('attachment', filename=title+'.jpg')
        async with self.session.post(url, data = payload) as response:
          x = await response.read()
          print(x)
```

Comment: But this reads the entire file contents into memory... I am dealing with huge files and need to stream them.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer only to the title of the post (and not the questions that are in between).

The following code should give a short example of how to upload a file from URL#1 to URL#2 (without the need to download the file to the local machine and only then do the upload).

I will give two examples here:

1. Read all the content of the file into the memory (not downloading). This is of-course not so good when working with huge files...
2. Read and send the file in chunks (so we won't read all the file content at once).

**Example #1:** Reading all file content **AT ONCE** and uploading

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp 

async def http_upload_from_url(src, dst):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        src_resp = await session.get(src)
        #print(src_resp)
        dst_resp = await session.post(dst, data=src_resp.content)
        #print(dst_resp)

try:
    asyncio.run(http_upload_from_url(SRC_URL, DST_URL))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**Example #2:** Reading file content **IN CHUNKS** and uploading

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp 

async def url_sender(url=None, chunk_size=65536):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        resp = await session.get(url)
        #print(resp)
        async for chunk in resp.content.iter_chunked(chunk_size):
            #print(f"send chunk with size {len(chunk)}")
            yield chunk

async def chunked_http_upload_from_url(src, dst):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        resp = await session.post(dst, data=url_sender(src))
        #print(resp)
        #print(await resp.text())

try:
    asyncio.run(chunked_http_upload_from_url(SRC_URL, DST_URL))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**Some notes:**

- You need to define SRC_URL and DST_URL.
- I've only added the prints for debug (in-case you don't get a [200 OK] response).